# How to set a max-width as percent AND pixels?

Tags: html, css, asset-pipeline

How can I prevent the width of a div from expanding beyond a percent AND a pixel? In other words, the browser should calculate the pixel value of the percent, and then choose the lower of the two values.

If I were to set them both like this: `{max-width:100px;max-width:20%;}` the asset pipeline would simply choose the second one and ignore the first one.

Comment: @dwreck08 I suppose, but I would be surprised if this couldn't be accomplished with pure CSS.

Comment: @Juhana's answer is the right way to go, but if your really need max-width, you could use a media query

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
width:20%;
max-width:100px;
```

This sets the width to 20% but caps it at 100 px.

Comment: -1, this doesn't answer the actual question. I guess it worked in the OPs case, but the question is: Where is the `max-width` in _percent_ in this answer? Instead the answer simply defines a `width`, which is something different.

Comment: @Zelphir I don't really understand your comment; the OP specifically wanted to set the width to either 20% or 100px, whichever is smaller, and this does exactly that.

Comment: That's not the same as setting two maximums and selecting the minimum of those. If the content did not fill `20%` of the _parent_, you'd still set the _element_ to be `20%` wide, while this might be not required or not wanted. If you have a max-width both for `px` and `%`, you'd not have this behavior.

Comment: @Zelphir quoting question: "In other words, the browser should calculate the pixel value of the percent, and then choose the lower of the two values." if parent width is 1000px then "pixel value of the percent" is 1000px * 20% = 200px. and then "lower of the two values" is 200px vs 100px. Juhana's answer is correct!

Comment: @JinJi Well, pick your choice, then the title of the question is misleading and ambigous.

Comment: @Zelphir The question is clear and does not conflict with the title, but this answer is indeed not correct.  Indeed the OP writes that the browser should choose the lowest value of the two, but it is implied that this value should then become the max-width, not the width.  I guess the current method would be to use CSS Grid layout and the [minmax()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax) function.

Answer (score 52):

One way to accomplish this is to simply use two divs

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    This content will not exceed 100px or 20% width.
  </div>
</div>

<style>
.outer {
  max-width: 90%;
}
.inner {
  max-width: 100px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 21):

You can now use css min. But you should note that IE does not support it.

```
width: min(20%, 100px)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min()

Comment: For additional info regarding browser support also see https://caniuse.com/css-math-functions

Comment: This is lovely. It works on `max-width` too in case you don't want to make the default width bigger.

Comment: "But you should note that IE does not support it."

Imagine my shock

Answer (score 10):

This will **NOT** work with different image sizes/aspect ratios. You can define *max-width* and *max-height* separately, if you know the sizes of images. Use this method for a specific group of images, but not as a general rule.

Practical example: You have 5 photos from your phone to be placed in a page and you need some text to be in the other half of screen. You reduce the size of images to 500px wide and 300px high. You want them not to exceed half the screen and not be wider than 250px on tablet. Calculate the max height: 250*300/500=150px.

```
.img-class {
    max-width: 50%;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .img-class {
       max-height: 150px;
    }
}
```

Tested on latest Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 7):

I had a specific problem which required a similar solution. I needed to display all images (independent of aspect-ratio, position or extra HTML markup) at their original size, up to a set maximum width in pixels. If the screen is smaller than this fixed size, it should shrink to fit. I.e. setting a `width` would not satisfy the requirements.

To expand on @Kiaurutis' answer:

```
img {
  max-width: 400px;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

A working example can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/vrehxmpx/. In this example there is an image greater than 400px (always scaled down) and an image smaller than the threshold (only scaled down when the screen is smaller than the image).

To adjust for margins, borders and other stuff you might have on the image, just increase the `@media`'s `max-width`.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't do this.**

I believe the selected answer is correct for the scenario that the OP describes. However, some of the comments argue that the OP has asked to set the `max-width` property to the lower of the two values, not the `width`. This also can be done, please see below.

**Note:** This solution does not make a lot of sense to me. Please use the selected answer, it correctly demonstrates what max-width was made for. The code below will ensure that the `max-width` property is the lesser of 20% or 100px.

```css
img {
    max-width: 20%;
}

@media (min-width: 500px){ /* at 500 pixels, 20% of the width will be 100px */
    img {
        max-width: 100px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same width "page wrap" on my site. I wanted it to be 95% width by default but not more than 1280px. here is how I made it with CSS

```
.wrap{max-width:95%;margin:0px auto;}
@media screen and (max-device-width:1280px),screen and (max-width:1280px){.wrap{max-width:1280px;margin:0px auto;}}
```